# Ubuntu 18.04 Stuck | Purple Dots

Tags: boot, 18.04

On Ubuntu 18.04 (5.4.0-113-generic kernel), everything was working fine until computer froze and I did a hard shut down (held power button). On restart I got stuck at the splash screen with four dots. I have checked some other posts and tried the following without being able to troubleshoot.

- Booting with an older kernel (5.4.0-113) (still stuck on splash screen, Ctl+T gets to a terminal and flashing cursor, but non-responsive to keyboard input)
- Booting in recovery mode (get lots of "OKs" then a flashing cursor I cannot type into).
- Tried to edit grub with adding line nomodset (still got stuck on splash screen)
  -I booted to a USB of 18.04 and ran sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1 (my linux fileststem).

I expect something is wrong with the video card or video card driver. But not sure why that would occur suddenly. The splash screen is more pixelated than usual. It looks the same as it did a few years ago when I installed Ubuntu and before I installed the nvidia driver.

But I am not sure it makes sense to blame the driver that had previously been working well for several years.

Answer (score 1):

After trying everything else, I booted to an Ubuntu 18.04 usb stick. Using "Try Ubuntu" I did the steps below. Eventually there was a line "free blocks count wrong for group. Fix ?". I got scared and spammed "N". Its possible I hit the space bar and it "Fix"ed it.

Regardless, I reboot to Ubuntu from the grub menu. This time under the splash screen is said something like "fsck checking disk, use F12 to quit" (or something like that).

I stepped away for a minute or two and came back. Ubuntu was working normally!

I assume doing my hard reset messed something up. Ill do everything to avoid that in the future.

First check your file system:

> boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode open a terminal
> window by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T type sudo fdisk -l identify the
> /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem" type sudo fsck -f
> /dev/sdXX, replacing sdXX with the number you found earlier repeat the
> fsck command if there were errors type reboot